# What is Web\x20Co in lsof -i

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

The last 2 lines of ***lsof -i*** are shown as below. What are those? I use OpenSuse LEAP 42.2.

```
Web\x20Co 7066 user1   38u  IPv4  76006      0t0  UDP *:43756 
Web\x20Co 7066 user1   39u  IPv6  76008      0t0  UDP *:46834
```

Comment: `\x20` is an escaped space character (` `).

Comment: You can above get more info about process 7066 by using `ps aux | grep 7066`. Or even more info by `ps -eo pid,user,group,args,etime,lstart | grep 7066`. My guess would be the Web server (Apache).

Comment: Do you have in your computer connected/built-in any component made by X20, possibly a network controller?

Comment: No, really. It’s a space. The actual executable or process name starts with "Web Co". You can easily replicate this by making a copy of `socat`, calling it `Web Content` and then making a network connection using that.

Answer (score 2):

The `\x20` string in the first column is a hexadecimal value for an ASCII character, in this case the space character. The output formatting used by lsof is described on the lsof man page.

```
Lsof only outputs printable (declared so by isprint(3)) 8 bit characters.  Non-printable characters are printed in one of three forms: the  C  ``\[bfrnt]''  form;  the
   control  character `^' form (e.g., ``^@''); or hexadecimal leading ``\x'' form (e.g., ``\xab'').  Space is non-printable in the COMMAND column (``\x20'') and printable
   elsewhere.
```

The man page describes that for the COMMAND column (shown on the left in the example output) the space character is treated as non-printable.

Answer (score 1):

#### The `\x20` is a space.

The `\x20` is a space "".
The  hexadecimal prefix `\x` is one of the 3 ways for`lsof` to print the *non-printable* characters.
The space in the ASCII table has value 32 in the decimal numeral system, **20** in *hex* and 040 *oct*.

As rule only characters with the octal ASCII value within 040 and 176 are considered *"printable"* by isprint <sup>[[isprint](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isprint&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports)]</sup> (see the table). In decimal are the characters within [32-126] included.

Interesting to note that the space is a printable character for `isprint`<sup>[[isprint](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isprint&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports),[isprint C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/)]</sup>, even if it has no graphical representation<sup>[*]</sup> and it is often used as a field separator.

Hence, in the man we find a supplementary line just for the space <sup>[[1](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html#OUTPUT)]</sup> and in the  COMMAND column:

> **Lsof only outputs printable** (declared so  by [isprint(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isprint&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports)) 8  bit  **characters**.
>   Non-printable characters  are printed in one of three forms:
>
> - the C '\[bfrnt]' form;
> - the   control character `^' form (e.g., ``^@'');
> - or **hexadecimal**  leading **'\x'** form (e.g., ``\xab'').
>
> **Space is non-printable in the COMMAND column (``\x20'') and printable elsewhere.**

<sup>(indentation and bold are mine)</sup>

#### Why the space is a non-printable character?

Interesting here is to know why it is considered *"non-printable"*.
It seems for security reasons, as we can read from the FAQ<sup>[[2](https://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/utils/admin-tools/lsof/FAQ)]</sup>:

> 14.5.1  Why is space considered a non-printable character in command
>       names?

```
Space is considered an unprintable character in command
names because it is sometimes possible to hide the full
command name from scripts that parse ps(1) output by
embedding a space in the name.
```

---

#### Some words more

If you are annoyed by this output you may consider to read the 
[OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html#OUTPUT_FOR_OTHER_PROGRAMS) section of the `lsof` man and the `-F` option specifications:

> When  the -F option is specified, lsof produces output that is suitable
>          for processing by another program - e.g, an awk or Perl script, or a  C program.
>   ...

---

<sup>[*] **Note:** It exists another function named `isgraph`<sup>[[isgraph C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isgraph/)]</sup> that checks whether c is a character with graphical representation but practically answers true for all those characters than can be printed (as by isprint) except the space character.</sup>